# Android Eclipse button going to top

Tags: button

Friends please help me i am tired of solving the issue, I am new with eclipse when i add any additional buttons or textview  or anything to the page it going to top of the page. I can't able to move that

Answer (score 0):

You should set the properties in xml file for the corresponding button.

```
<Button
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
  />
```

You should try such properties according to your requirement.

Comment: Yes you can do manually or in eclipse you can use graphical interface to drag and drop to required position

Comment: Yes but when i do the graphical option i getting like http://gyazo.com/777be86a008078bf587f4a4a6e98f9fa

Comment: Then you go for manual writing of the xml codes. I think your graphical option is not properly enabled

Comment: I am really tired with this problem :(

Comment: How can i enable that ?

Comment: I can able to add and move buttons and such all works in fragment xml but not in any other xml files !

Answer (score 0):

This problem may be caused because from the fragments, added in the newer SDKs. I had the similar problem and my solution was changing several thing in the onCreate function:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }
```

to this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);


    }
```

After this change you should be able to use the graphical interface and position your Views. (You should use fragment_main.xml)

That fixed the problem for me. But it is not a good solution for the problem if you want to use fragments though.